# Parameters between Struts2 Actions

Tags: jsp, struts2, request, action

I need to stay on the same page after Item update, but I need the item id to know where to go on success. I tried a few examples:

**First one:**

```
    <action
        name="add-item"
        method="addItem"
        class="com.deveto.struts.actions.ItemsAction" >
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">show-update-item</param>
            <param name="itemId">${itemId}</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

**Second one:**

```
    With an Action variable and setter & getter methods.
```

and

```
    <action
        name="add-item"
        method="addItem"
        class="com.deveto.struts.actions.ItemsAction" >
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">show-update-item</result>
    </action>
```

**Third one:**

```
    With request.setAttribute("itemId", itemId); and request.getAttribute("itemId");
```

and

```
    <action
        name="add-item"
        method="addItem"
        class="com.deveto.struts.actions.ItemsAction" >
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">show-update-item</result>
    </action>
```

**Fourth one:**

```
    With an Action variable and setter & getter methods.
```

and the type="chain"

```
    <action
        name="add-item"
        method="addItem"
        class="com.deveto.struts.actions.ItemsAction" >
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        <result name="success" type="chain">show-update-item</result>
    </action>
```

Eventually the Action is one, show-update-item.action.

But all of this is giving me the same null result.

Any advices?

**Ex: show-update-item.action?itemId=33 (getParameter of itemId) -> editing some textfields -> submit (with itemId=33 in request) -> on succes redirectAction -> show-update-item.action (here when I try to getAttribute it is null)**

Comment: Are you accessing the request object directly? If so you should be using getParameter not getAttribute.

Comment: Of course, getParameter is for the first time when I go to that action, but for the second time when I am just refreshing the action I need to set it to the request again, and after that I need to getAttribute, right?

Comment: It might be helpful to show the code for your second action. If the parameter is being passed to the second action, the getter method should be able to handle retrieval from the request object and then you can simply access it via the value stack. If you want to use request only, you'll need to set the id to a request attribute ie request.setAttribute(itemId), but you'll have to do this with every request.

Comment: Is the same action, but for the first time it gets the value from parameter, and for the second one, from the request, if parameter is null. I already made that, I wrote this method as Third one in my post.

Comment: If it's the same action then you need to get rid of the redirectAction type. The only time you need to use redirectAction is if you're passing things to a completely separate action. If you are using the same action with each request the parameter should be maintained in the value stack.

Comment: I used already redirectAction, please read my post, it is resulting in null

Comment: What action class is used for show-update-item?

Comment: In <result name="success" type="redirectAction">show-update-item</result>, what class is used for show-update-item? Does this action use class="com.deveto.struts.actions.ItemsAction"? If so, there is no reason to even have another action/redirect, on success you would just reference the appropriate jsp page.

Comment: this is the same action show-update-item.action -> add-item.action -> success -> show-update-item.action

Comment: Please post the code where you actually use "show-update-item.action". Also, can you verify that when the redirect actually happens that you see "show-update-item.action?itemId=33", and not just "show-update-item.action" in your browser?

Comment: I answered for you below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're staying on the same page with a different action after an item is selected on the first action. If this is the case, your first action definition should work:

```
<action
    name="add-item"
    method="addItem"
    class="com.deveto.struts.actions.ItemsAction" >
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">show-update-item</param>
        <param name="itemId">${itemId}</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

Now that being said, you need to make sure you have accessor methods in both actions (we'll call them action 1 and action 2) for itemId.

In action 1 ${itemId} is being retreived through the getter and in action 2 ${itemId} should be set through the setter method.

Another option would be to consider using sessionaware. Simply set a session variable in action 1 and in action 2 retrieve the session variable and remove it from session if you're concerned about overhead. I tend to use session more often than not.

Comment: I not really want to create a session, I try hard to use them rarely, only in cases of authorization, internationalization, etc.. I thought about the session, but I'm more than a perfectionist, so I want to try to find a solution within a request. I edited my post, you may try to look at the end to see what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Like Russel suggested, use this action:

```
    <action
        name="add-item"
        method="addItem"
        class="com.deveto.struts.actions.ItemsAction" >
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">show-update-item</param>
            <param name="itemId">${itemId}</param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

Make sure you have accessor methods on ItemsAction. Make sure you are using them to get the value of "itemId" and NOT "getAttribute".

```
public String getItemId() {
    return itemId;
}

public void setItemId(String itemId) {
    this.itemId = itemId;
}
```

Verify that when the final redirect actually happens, that you actually do see "show-update-item.action?itemId=33" in your browser's address bar. If "itemId" is not being passed in the query than there is absolutely no way for you to get the value of "itemId".

Comment: Should I answer? hey, yes, I already used that, and I am sure that I have this methods, please read my post above, to see what is the problem, thanks for your help.